# Scheduled reminder linked to deleted event is not deleted: bug or feature?

Tags: civievent

Create an event with a scheduled reminder (e.g. to send a confirmation 1 day before the start).
Then delete the event.
==> the scheduled reminder is not deleted (see Administer > Communication > Scheduled reminders)

I would expect the scheduled reminder would be deleted as well.
Is this a bug or a feature?
What would be your expectation?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say its a bug, rather missing feature. The schedule reminder UI also allows to update the reminder to include more events(for reminder which was configured from events tab) so it is additional discussion to delete the reminder if its only used for deleted event or disable it so that we maintain the log history if incase any reminder was sent for the reminder.

Would appreciate if you can send a PR to core to delete the reminder.